# Static maps shadow parameter ignored

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-static-api

Beginning today, my Static Maps are showing a new behavior. My custom markers no longer display their shadows, and as a result their positions are wrong. I remember something like this happened with the introduction of 'visual refresh', however I am not using that parameter.

I tried adding shadow:true (shouldn't be necessary) and this seems to be ignored.

I realise that today (19 November 2013) is the day that v2 of the Google Maps API will be retired, so maybe my problem is related to that.

Can anyone shed light on this mystery?

Comment: Are you still using version 2? Google itself states: "all applications requesting v2 will be served a special, wrapped version of the v3 API instead", so if you are using v2 and it started today, I would say: yes, this is related and you should migrate to version 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today (20 November 2013), the Google Static Maps API documentation has not been updated to reflect a change in the display of custom icons that appears to be linked with the retirement of Google Maps API v2.

Prior to the v2 retirement, static maps custom icons displayed a shadow (shadow:true was the default); their "anchor point" was set at the bottom center of the custom icon image, from where the shadow was cast. Now, shadows are turned off by default (a bug?) and the anchor point is set at the center of the custom icon image. The image effectively obscures the point, making my maps "pointless".

To remedy this, I added `visual_refresh=false` to my URLs. The visual_refresh parameter was introduced earlier this year as a way for developers to opt-in to the new, beautified maps. See: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ch/2013/05/a-fresh-new-look-for-maps-api-for-all.html

The example image illustrating Google Static Maps custom icons (see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index#CustomIcons) no longer displays as it should (shadows on by default). Adding `visual_refresh=false` to the image src URL returns the map to its intended state.

I don't know for how long this solution will be necessary. It would be great if someone from Google would update this question when the Static Maps API is corrected!

Comment: I guess 'flat' is in and 3D is out.. but map pins need to be in the right place!

Comment: Yes, same problem here... the workaround I used was to double the image. Basically, Google centers the pin to its location. So if you add some transparent pixels below your image (basically double the height and place the actual image to the top) it works. Hackish but does the job.

Comment: Thanks, I read a similar idea on another thread.  As it is, custom markers are rendered useless. I expect that this will eventually be acknowledged as a bug. There is no 'point' if the marker covers up the place being mapped.

Comment: As of today (at least I noticed today) custom markers are correctly positioned without using the "visual_refresh" parameter, however shadows - supposed to be the default - are still missing!

Comment: Ironically I want to do the opposite; only fixing the anchor at the bottom centre is very limiting, it means you can only use pointed markers.  If it was always in the middle you could still implement a pointed marker (with transparency) but could also implement others.  Bring back the "bug"!